# How to give relational condition in pg_select function

Tags: php

In `pg_select` function the third argument is a array used to specify the column name and its value.

It works like an and condition if we give more than one key => value.
I have id column in my table I want to fetch the rows which has id value more than 1000.

How to give value in associative array in `pg_select` function for the above requirement.

I need answer without using `pg_query` function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pg_select is too simple for this. You have to write the full query one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

you can using SQL:

```
pg_query("select * from table_name where id <1000 ");
```